# Rendering Plot in Flexdashboard with Shiny

Tags: ggplot2, shiny, render, flexdashboard, ggplotly

I'm trying to render a plot in a flexdashboard that is incorporating elements of Shiny. When I pass my plot through renderPlotly(), the plot generates in my output, but the axis cuts off, and the bars do not display. This is the code I'm using to render the plot:

```
renderPlotly({
income_dat %>%
  drop_na(q41_what_is_the_estimated_yearly_income_of_your_household) %>%
  ggplot(aes(q41_what_is_the_estimated_yearly_income_of_your_household)) +
  geom_bar(fill = "#A1A75F") +
  coord_flip() +
  facet_wrap(input$demo1) +
  labs(x = "",
       y = "Total")
})
```

Conversely, when I use renderPlot() instead of renderPlotly, the plot does render, but it is extremely small and fixed to the top left corner of the plot area on the dashboard.

Here's a segment of my data:

```
 head(income_dat)
# A tibble: 6 × 6
  response_id q1_in_which_coun… q2_are_you_native_… q3_what_is_your… q41_what_is_the_… gender_id
  <fct>       <fct>             <fct>               <fct>            <fct>             <fct>    
1 39          Honolulu          No                  55 +             Prefer not to an… Female   
2 40          Maui              No                  55 +             $125,000 - less … Female   
3 41          I don't live in … No                  25 - 34          NA                NA       
4 42          Honolulu          Yes                 35 - 44          $105,000 - less … Male     
5 43          Kaua'i            No                  55 +             $65,000 - less t… Male     
6 44          Maui              No                  55 +             Prefer not to an… Male
```

The variables for county, gender identity, age group, and Hawaiian native status are the variables I'm trying to pass as my shiny inputs with input$demo1, and the income variable is what I'm trying to plot on geom_bar, where the discrete response options of income brackets will populate the axis.

Any input on how to render this plot correctly, with either renderPlotly() or renderPlot() would be appreciated.

Comment: Please share your data using `dput(df)`?

Comment: Sorry for not including data in the original post. I have edited and input data above.